# How this stdout redirection works?

Tags: c++, c, programming-languages

Code below redirects stdout to a file fname & then redirects back to original stdout. It works fine for me. 
But I am not able to understand how it actually works. If anyone can help me understand I will appreiciate it.

```
    printf("\n This is console");
    fflush(stdout);
    fgetpos(stdout, &pos);
    fd = dup(fileno(stdout));
    freopen(fname, "a+", stdout);   

    printf("inside file op");  

    fflush(stdout);
    dup2(fd,fileno(stdout));
    close(fd);
    clearerr(stdout);
    fsetpos(stdout, &pos);
    printf("\nBack to Console");
```

Comment: yes , copy that. will keep in mind. thanks :)

Comment: Ghreat gods above, why would anyone want to do _that_? (Besides as a desperate last-ditch workaround for a source-less library that insists on writing to stdout, that is).

Comment: if someone wants to redirect different log messages to different files for debugging purposes, its quite handy for that.

Comment: You should ditch your logging infrastructure in favor of something that let you control the destination in a saner way, then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's go through it line by line. The first line prints something to `stdout`:

```
printf("\n This is console");
```

Then it flushes `stdout` so all the remaining data in the buffer gets sent to `stdout` and won't get mixed up with the file data:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Now we store the current position of ourselves in `stdout` because otherwise if `stdout` was already directed to a file, we might (?) overwrite earlier parts of it.

```
fgetpos(stdout, &pos);
```

Now we clone the file descriptor of what's currently `stdout`. Since we're about to change where `stdout` points to, we need to keep a copy of the original:

```
fd = dup(fileno(stdout));
```

Now that we have everything preserved, we can reopen `stdout` as the file:

```
freopen(fname, "a+", stdout);
```

At this point, `stdout` has been redirected to the file. We can now print to it:

```
printf("inside file op");
```

Now we're done printing to the file. We need to flush `stdout` (now the file) so it doesn't get mixed up with the normal `stdout` data:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

After that, we clone the original `stdout` file descriptor over the current `stdout` descriptor.

```
dup2(fd,fileno(stdout));
```

The cloned one can be closed now:

```
close(fd);
```

I'm not quite sure why this is here but this clears any errors that occurred writing to the file:

```
clearerr(stdout);
```

Now we restore our position in `stdout`. Again, as far as I know, this is only useful if it was originally redirected to a file:

```
fsetpos(stdout, &pos);
```

Now we're back to the original `stdout`, so we can print again:

```
printf("\nBack to Console");
```

Comment: sounds great .. now its much more clear.
thanks appreciate it.

Comment: I think it's pretty efficient as is. If you wanted to be more efficient you might be able to skip the Standard C Library (except for `fflush`, which you'll probably want to keep) and go directly to system calls (like `dup`, `dup2`, and `close` there) but I don't think you'll gain much from that.

Comment: Using `freopen` in this way is not safe. Instead you should simply `open` the new file (or `fopen` it then get its `fileno`) and `dup2` it on top of file descriptor 1.